# Showing popup with info about all markers in the clustered marker in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, clustering, popup, markers

I'm using Leaflet PlugIn markercluster for leaflet https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster to visualize Points.
My goal is to stop the process of "getting closer" to the points, so marker won't be created. The idea behind it is, to not show the exact location of the point.

Im think about a visualization like this:

[image]

The best would be if I can set the radius I want all Points to be clustered and then just showing the result of the cluster not the point itself. When clicking the Cluster I want to get the information of all the points within a cluster, but not the points visualized.

Below you can find the code I have so far.

```
 var map = new L.Map("map").setView([50.110924, 8.682127],11);
    

    var cartodbAttribution = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>';

    var positron = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: cartodbAttribution
    }).addTo(map);
    
    


  var dcStyle = {
   
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 0.5,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillColor: "yellow",
            fillOpacity: 0.3,
    
  };
  

  var ffm =
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=cite:ffm&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=epsg:4326";



  $.getJSON(ffm).then((res) => {
    var layer = L.geoJson(res, {
     

      style: dcStyle,
    }).addTo(map);

    map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
  });
    var dc = 
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=cite:dc&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=epsg:4326";

const markers = new L.markerClusterGroup({
    spiderfyOnMaxZoom:false,
    showCoverageOnHover: false,
    });

 $.getJSON(dc).then((res) => {
    var layer = L.geoJson(res, {
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
           const popupContent =
          '<h4 class = "text-primary">Information</h4>'+
           '<div class="container"><table class="table table-striped">' +
          "<thead><tr><th>Properties</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead>" +
          "<tbody><tr><td> Name </td><td>" +
          feature.properties.dc_name;
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
      },  
    pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
        return markers.addLayer(L.circleMarker(latlng,geojsonMarkerOptions)) 
        },
    }).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(layer.getBound());
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, I hope it is more clear now. Its not so easy to explain...

Comment: Read the Leaflet.Markercluster documentation. Specifically, the bit about `zoomToBoundsOnClick`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I read that, but it is not stopping the points from seperating out of the cluster. My goal is to keep the points clustered and just get the information from the points in a PopUp or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display popup upon marker cluster click with info about all the markers in the cluster, there are several things needed:

- cluster marker layer `markers` has to be created with `zoomToBoundsOnClick: false` option, to prevent markers to be unclustered upon click;
- event processing function for marker cluster `clusterclick` has to be set, where popup is defined and triggered, with info from all the markers in the cluster;
- basic GeoJSON layer `layer` with unclustered markers has to be added to the clustered marker layer `markers`, and this layer then to the map.

Code could then look something like this:

```
const markers = new L.markerClusterGroup({
  spiderfyOnMaxZoom:false,
  showCoverageOnHover: false,
  zoomToBoundsOnClick: false
});
markers.on('clusterclick', function(evt) {
  var clusterMarkers = evt.layer.getAllChildMarkers();
  var popupContent =
    '<h4 class = "text-primary">Information</h4>'+
    '<div class="container"><table class="table table-striped">' +
    '<thead><tr><th>Properties</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead>' +
    '<tbody>';
  clusterMarkers.forEach(function(marker) {
    popupContent += '<tr><td>Name</td><td>' + marker.feature.properties.dc_name + '</td></tr>';
  });
  popupContent += '</tbody></table></div>';
  var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng(evt.latlng)
    .setContent(popupContent)
    .openOn(map);
});

$.getJSON(dc).then((res) => {
  var layer = L.geoJson(res, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
      const popupContent =
        '<h4 class = "text-primary">Information</h4>'+
        '<div class="container"><table class="table table-striped">' +
        '<thead><tr><th>Properties</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead>' +
        '<tbody>' +
        '<tr><td> Name </td><td>"' + feature.properties.dc_name + '</td></tr>' +
        '</tbody></table></div>';
      layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    },  
    pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
      return L.circleMarker(latlng,geojsonMarkerOptions);
    }
  }).addTo(markers);
  markers.addTo(map);
  map.fitBounds(markers.getBound());
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working perfectly

Comment: Issue is just that with double click it is still seperating the cluster to the points location. But I have to think about a solution to solve that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with clusters, its Leaflet double click zoom. To prevent it, use map's `doubleClickZoom: false` option.

Comment: Sure, with that I can not zoom in by double clicking. I dont want to disable zooming I wont to disable the cluster the be seperated into the single points when zooming in. I think then I have to use a cluster method not based on zooming.

Comment: For that see option `disableClusteringAtZoom`.

Comment: If you have another/new question, please post it as a separate question.